# Word VBA - Expand a header if a certain checkbox is ticked?

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word, expand, word-contentcontrol

Used VB for Excel, but new to VB for Word. I'm not sure how to expand a heading if a certain checkbox is marked true. This is the code I currently have and I get a run time error saying that the requested member of the collection does not exist, but I have named the CheckBox in the properties window of the control. I am using Version 1808 (Build 10730.20262 Click-to-Run) of Microsoft Word.

```
Sub Macro1()

If ActiveDocument.FormFields("Licensing_1").CheckBox.Value = True Then
    Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False
        If Selection.Text Like "Licensing Discovery Questions" Then
        Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
        Selection.Find.Execute
            Else: Selection.Paragraphs(1).CollapsedState = True
        Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
        Selection.Find.Execute
    End If
Loop
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure the checkbox is a FormField checkbox? If you're unsure, which command was used to insert it to the document? Also, could you give me the more "popular" version number of Word, please? (2010, 2013, 2016/365...)

Comment: @CindyMeister It is Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus. I did not make the document, but they are check box content controls. I do not know if those are considered the same thing.

Comment: No, content controls and form fields are *not* the same - which is why you're getting the error. Give me a few minutes to cobble up some sample code for getting the value of a content control checkbox...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike form fields, multiple Word content controls can have the same designation (name - the actual term is `Title`). For this reason, it's not possible to use the string as an index value - it's not guaranteed to be unique.

For this reason, it's necessary to use the method `SelectContentControlsByTitle` (or `SelectContentControlsByTag`) to pick up a content control object. The method returns a *Collection* of content controls - all that have the same Title or Tag. (Note: these are case-sensitive!).

If the code should work with all of these content controls, then use a `For Each` loop with the collection.

If the code should work with only one content control (the first, for example), this can be specified using the `ContentControls.Item` property.

On the assumption there is only one checkbox in the document that has the designation "Licensing_1":

```
Sub CheckBox_CC()
    Dim ccCheckBox As Word.ContentControl
    Dim doc As Word.Document

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set ccCheckBox = doc.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Licensing_1").Item(1)

    If ccCheckBox.Checked Then
        'Do things here
    End If
End Sub
```